# Change something in the clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The first 2 div's comes from database the 3rd is a clone.
The problem is that I whant to change the clone but if i do that all div's will change.

What I whant:

1- the red line (is if the value is false) must not be applied to the clone

2- the clone must replace the 2 spans (icon) with 1 (another icon) span

[image]

the code i use for the clone is

```
$(document).on("input", ".add", function(obj){
    if ($(this).next(".add").length > 0){

  } else {
        $(this).clone().insertAfter( this ).find("input:text").val("");
  }
});
```

the code i use for the red line is

```
$('.statuss').each (function(obj){

    if ($(this).val() == "False")
        {

            $(this).parent().find('div').css("background", "#ff8080");
        }})
```

sorry for not beeing able to give a fiddle.

EDIT:

the 2 icons are (ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick and ui-icon.ui-icon-check) must be replaced with (ui-icon-close)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to make changes into the clone, Hope this helps.

```
$(this)
.clone()
.removeClass()
.addClass('ui-icon.ui-icon-close')
.appendTo('body');
```

As per your question, I understand that you would like to create a clone of an element with few new changes. I just show you an idea how to do that, you can do necessary changes as per your need.

See working snippet for more details.

```js
$('a.clone').click(function(){
  $('.neeToClone')
    .clone()
    .removeClass('ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick ui-icon.ui-icon-check neeToClone')
    .addClass('ui-icon.ui-icon-close')
    .css('color', 'red')
    .html('Clonned DIV')
    .appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick and ui-icon.ui-icon-check neeToClone">Div-1</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clone">Clone</a>
```

**Edit-1: Added new code**

```
$(document).on("input", ".yourDiv", function(){
    if ($(this).next(".yourDiv").length > 0){
    console.log("There is already a Clone of this Div")
  } else {
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    $(clone).find('span.ui-icon-closethick').removeClass('ui-icon ui-icon-closethick').addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-close');
    $(clone).find('span.ui-icon-check').remove();
    $(clone).insertAfter(this).find("input:text").val("");
  }
});
```

Comment: I couldn't use it i don't know whij but it didn't work

Comment: Show me your HTML or create a jsfiddle to identify the exact problem.
As I understand from your question that you would like to create a clone of an element with few changes in the icons and style, That s what I am doing over here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cqenvvt9/2/

similiar to this fiddle

only what i whant is when it creates a clone it only shows 1 span with the class ui-icon ui-icon-close (so instead of 2 spans it has to show 1)

Comment: and is it possible that the function of that new icon is  $(this).parent().find('.veld').val('')

Comment: @S.Oruc I've updated my answer and added new code under Title "Edit-1: Added new code", check it now

Comment: Is it possible to show the close icon when i refresh the page because now it changes only when i type something in

Comment: You can do it in $(document).ready(function(){ //your code }); instead of on method.

Comment: if i use document. ready  non of my code works -_-'' 
well thnx for ur support

Comment: Okay just let me know if you still face any issues and accept my answer if it helped you.